# How to display data from a java variable in an HTML form?

Tags: java, html, web-applications

I have a simple setup where I have an html form where I ask a user to enter a number in a textbox then click submit.

Then in java I take the number and use it for an SQL query, then from the resulting query I store certain results in java variables and I'd like to display stored results on the HTML page.

I was wondering how I can print java variables on my html page?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show code and efforts. For example it is not clear if you mean JAVA (server programming language) or JavaScript (client side or server side scripting language)

Comment: How does your UI and back end code talks? Please share the piece of code here.

Comment: You can easily render Java variables e.g. using JSF.